# Using partition by in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions, partition-by

I'm trying to recreate the code used in this article https://blog.getdbt.com/modeling-marketing-attribution/ but the main difference is that I have to use SQLite. I cannot figure out why I am unable to create fields that will form the foundation for me to calculate the number of attribution points to assign to each session. I'm not sure if I am using the "partition by" function properly.

The data translated from the article to mine is:

- Sessions = Impressions
- Customer_ID = Onovative_ID

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

**QUERY:**

```
select
*,
count(*) over (
partition by on_id
) as total_sessions,

row_number() over (
partition by on_id
order by sessions.started_at
) as session_number

from
//step 2
(
select impressions.*, loans.opendt 
from (
select "Onovative Id" as on_id, impdt as impression_date, "Email" as medium , Template as type
from Emails
UNION
select "Onovative Id", impdt, Type, "CIQ"
from Outbound
UNION
select "CIQ ID", impdt, Channnel, "Channel Detail"
from ImageWorks
) as impressions
join Listing loans on loans."Onovative Id" = impressions.on_id
where 
impression_date <= opendt
and impression_date > date(opendt,'-30 day')
--order by on_id
) as two
```

**WORKING QUERY:**

```
select impressions.*, loans.opendt 
from (
select "Onovative Id" as on_id, impdt as impression_date, "Email" as medium , Template as type
from Emails
UNION
select "Onovative Id", impdt, Type, "CIQ"
from Outbound
UNION
select "CIQ ID", impdt, Channnel, "Channel Detail"
from ImageWorks
) as impressions
join Listing loans on loans."Onovative Id" = impressions.on_id
where 
impression_date <= opendt
and impression_date > date(opendt,'-30 day')
```

OUTPUT of WORKING QUERY:

```
on_id    impression_date              medium               type       opendt
10001    2020-07-02 00:00             Letter    ImageWorks Refi              2020-07-29 00:00
70001    2020-07-20 00:00             Postcard              ImageWorks SmartTrack               2020-07-29 00:00
03301    2020-08-25 11:57             Email     CIQ         2020-09-21 00:00
02201    2020-05-11 00:00             Postcard              ImageWorks SmartTrack               2020-06-01 00:00
50001    2020-09-16 10:21             Email     CIQ         2020-09-28 00:00
10001    2020-09-16 10:21             Email    product offer e-statements email             2020-09-28 00:00
00601    2020-09-19 09:30             Email     CIQ         2020-09-28 00:00
00901    2020-09-16 10:21             Email     CIQ         2020-10-05 00:00
00501    2020-09-16 10:21             Email    product offer e-statements email             2020-10-05 00:00
00101    2020-09-19 09:30             Email     CIQ         2020-10-05 00:00
00401    2020-10-01 09:42             Email     CIQ         2020-10-05 00:00
00801    2020-10-04 16:14             Email     CIQ         2020-10-05 00:00
00301    2020-07-18 11:11             Email     CIQ         2020-07-28 00:00
00012    2020-06-08 11:43             Direct Mail Large Postcard           CIQ         2020-07-03 00:00
```

````
**SYNTAX ERROR: (doesn’t give line number)**

``` [14:41:37] Error while executing SQL query on database 'save_pandas3': near "(": syntax error```
````

Comment: Window functions were introduced in SQLite in version 3.25.0 Check the version of SQLite you have.

Comment: Please, provide the exact version of you SQLite. Also you should add `CREATE TABLE` statements and correctly indent your code (adding indentation for each new level of subquery) because it is really hard to check unformatted code without table structures and guess where that *near "("* appear. Also remove extra tags, because MySQL is not the same as SQLite.

Comment: Also as long as I've tried to format your code I've found that there's no table `sessions` and column `started_at` in your query. So it definitely not a working query. Also you should avoid quoted identifiers (like `"Onovative Id"`) because they can produce a lot of errors in code and sometimes are handled very poorly (if on some day you'll decide to use some additional tool for your DB)

Comment: It seems your `row_number` should probably  `ORDER BY impression_date`. And note that `//step2` is not valid syntax. If you wanted to include the comment, then `--step2` or `/*step2*/` could be valid here.

Comment: @forpas, you are correct. I am CHart's colleague, you answered my last question correctly, and you are right again on his!